# What does the word "current" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

But in no other country than India has this current anti-minority, far-right politics resulted in a concerted pattern of lunch attacks against minorities.

The word "current" as an adjective (reason why I think it's been used as an adjective is that it is there before "anti-minority". It'd have been different if it was used after that.) means - happening or existing now.

But that seems to make little sense to me because it would mean that it(anti minority) is there for now. But I don't think that is what being implied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "current" in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/current) is shown as

> **current**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Belonging to the present time; happening or being used or done now.
>
> *keep abreast of current events*

In the sentence, it qualifies **politics**, along with the two other adjectival phrases "anti-minority" and "far-right".